# Unable to correct error to load <lang="scss"> in vue style

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, webpack-style-loader

i am developing an application with webpackconfig , i have installed "sass-loader" and "node-sass" and tried all the different configurations i have found both in the official webpack documentation and in other web references to load scss and i can't solve the following error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?sourceMap!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-311067c8","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/components/devis/animal.vue
ERROR in ./src/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader, css-loader, sass-loader' in 'C:\Users\juan.urra\Desktop\pricing_3108'
 @ ./src/main.js 9:0-46
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "vue-cli",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules",
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.16.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.11",
    "vue-mq": "^1.0.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.3.4",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.5",
    "vuex": "^3.5.1"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "less": "^3.12.2",
    "less-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.10",
    "sass-loader": "^9.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "stylus": "^0.54.8",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.4",
    "webpack": "^3.12.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
  }
}
```

this is my webpack.config

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            'scss': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader'
            ],
            'sass': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
            ]
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'fonts/'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  watch: true,
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"',
        BASE_URL_API: '"https:///"',
        USER: '"j.doe1"',
        PASSWORD: '"password"',
        PAYMENT_URL: '"https:///"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
} else {
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"development"',
        BASE_URL_API: '"https:///"',
        USER: '"j.doe1"',
        PASSWORD: '"password"',
        PAYMENT_URL: '"https:///"'
      }
    })
  ])
}
```

and the error jumps when I refer to the lang "scss" in the style tag

Should I make any reference in my main.js? I haven't seen anything about it in any reference

I'm stuck in this error and I can't fix it in any way! Someone who can make me see the error!
Greetings and thanks in advance for your time and help

Answer (score 1):

after trying all the solutions I found on the web and not seeing the error I found a github repository with a similar project in structure to mine and reviewing the package.json I saw that the only difference was the version of 'sass-loader'. Mine was by default the last version and yours was an older one, so I downloaded the version to yours and the problem was solved. I understand that there is some kind of incompatibility between webpack and sass loader versions, although I have not found any reference to the issue. I hope to help.